# Write php code in java script tag without double quote

Tags: php, jquery

I want to write echo php variable in jquery without single or double quote. Below is my code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.your').slick({
 autoplay: <?php echo $autoPlay; ?>,
 autoplaySpeed: 2000,
 dots: true,
 infinite: true,
 speed: 300,
 slidesToShow: 4,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 responsive: [
 {
  breakpoint: 1024,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    infinite: true,
    dots: true
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 600,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 2
  }
},
{
  breakpoint: 480,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
},{
  breakpoint: 320,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
}
]
});
});
```

I want to echo $autoplay without double quote. When i write without double quote, its gave me error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Any one help me to find out the exact solution for this

Comment: What does `$autoplay` look like? Is it a string like `true` or `false`?

Comment: yes $autoplay = true or false

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's no value to `$autoPlay`.. you can prevent errors such as that by providing a *default* value... example:

```
autoplay: <?php echo isset($autoPlay) ? $autoPlay : '0'; ?>,
```

If `autoplay` is a boolean, then you need to echo something else, such as:

```
autoplay: <?php echo $autoPlay ? '1' : '0'; ?>,
```

Both of these use ternary operators - see http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: If `autoplay` is a boolean, try my second example.

Comment: I used your second example but its doesn't run

Comment: then `autoplay: <?php echo $autoPlay ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>,` would work. Either way "1" and "0" (without quotes) in JS is evaluated as true/false... so I don't see the issue. Maybe issue lies elsewhere. Are you *sure* `$autoPlay` has something in it? Try using `var_dump($autoPlay)` to make sure.

Comment: I used ternary operation and resolved

    (Mage::getStoreConfig('productslider/new_viewed_config/new_autoStart_block_enable') == 1) ? 'true' : 'false';

Comment: Sometimes it helps to know what variables you are using, in what system, etc.. we usually try to answer in an agnostic fashion. Be sure to mark as answered!